Webex modifies special characters in url shared through messages api
So, I am trying to send a link through my Webex bot which has some request params in the URL. This works fine in the web browser but when someone opens the message on webex ios app, webex changes the special characters like '&' and '=' to html encoded characters.  How can I stop Webex from doing that ?
'='  gets converted to  '=' and '&' gets converted to '&%23x3D;'
Is there anyway I can instruct webex not to do it ?
Btw, I am sharing an adaptive card in the request body.
